# AJAX calls using .net core

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to open a popup when I click on forgot password link and on send email button on pop send post request and move to next popup for verifying the OTP

Link which triggers modal to open

```
<label class="flex">Password <a href="#" class="ml-auto  small" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1">Forget Password?</a></label>
```

Modal popup code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Modal 1</p>
                    <input id="forgotPasswordEmail" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                    @*<a href="#modal-2" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Next ></a>*@
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="sendOTP"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Send email</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

AJAX call to asp.net core controller

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#sendOTP").click(function (e) {
                alert("Hi");
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Auth/ForgetPassword/",
                    data: {
                        userName: $("#forgotPasswordEmail").val()
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

But the issue is that function is not triggered as I have added an alert to get if the AJAX function is getting called? Can anyone let me know if I am missing anything

Comment: Have you checked the browser console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Is the JavaScript being executed before the target HTML content exists on the page?  (For example, if this JavaScript is in the page's header, or if the HTML content is dynamically added after the page has already loaded.)  Are there any errors at all on the browser's console?  Do you have more than one element with that `id`?  If you do `console.log($("#sendOTP"));` just before assigning the `click` handler, what does it output to the console?

Comment: I have checked the browser but I do have any errors.

Comment: @David It is not in header section it is below the code

Comment: Not what might be causing you the issue, but this is semantically invalid: `button type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

It's Ok on my side. Perhaps this is caused by the element's id conflict. Do you have any other elements with the same id `sendOTP`. You can try to use name selector.

```
<button id="sendOTP" name="sendOTP" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Send email</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[name=sendOTP]").click(function (e) {
        alert("Hi");
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Auth/ForgetPassword/",
            data: {
                userName: $("#forgotPasswordEmail").val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Update:**

```
<button id="sendOTP" onclick="sendOTP()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send email</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendOTP() {
        alert("Hi");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Auth/ForgetPassword/",
            data: {
                userName: $("#forgotPasswordEmail").val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I checked but there is no id conflict.

Comment: Maybe you can try my update. Add the onclink event in the button element.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think "e.preventDefault()" is necessary is here because we usually use this when submitting a form via onSubmit attribute in  you can define your function and event listener like below and i think it will work.

```
$("#buttonId or...").click(function () {
    alert("Hi");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Auth/ForgetPassword/",
        data: {
            userName: $("#forgotPasswordEmail").val()
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

i think that will work